# Changing email column name in laravel 5.6 in default users table

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

I have my own users table which I want to use in auth, but the problem is the email field is "userEmail" instead of "email".

For login page I overided the below method in LoginController.php

```
public function username()
{
    return 'userEmail';
}
```

and changed the name in input field.

```
<input id="userEmail" type="email" name="userEmail" value="{{ old('userEmail') }}" class="{{ $errors->has('userEmail') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}">
```

this is working fine for login, **Need solution for Forgot Password and Reset Password forms as they are not working**.

So any solution for it in Laravel 5.6

Comment: It's probably easier to just rename your table column.

Comment: @apokryfos ya a lot easier but I can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could add accessor and mutator methods to the user model:

```
public function getEmailAttribute() {
    return $this->attributes['userEmail'];
}

public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['userEmail'] = $value;
}
```

[Docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

To save modifying php code (and breaking something), it might be easier creating a sql view of your users table and map the actual field names to the names the User class is using e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW v_user_auth AS
SELECT user_id AS id
, user_created_time AS created_at
, user_updated_time AS updated_at
, user_name AS name
, user_email AS email
, user_password AS password
, user_remember_token AS remember_token
FROM t_user
```

In the User.class add the following to get it to use the view:

```
protected $table = 'v_user_auth';
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can leverage on Laravel Mutators:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Haven't got the time to test the following but should be what you're looking for:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's email.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }
}
```